Spring batch write items not on chunk size
I have an following JdbcCursorItemReader and writer.I am writing items according to chunk size but now I want to make sure that I need to write every time 10K items from the reader in one json file which I will get from table1. So that when my items are written I can delete those entry from table1.
Right now I am deleting those entry in listener as chunk is written but the problem is if I need to resume job which has failed in between chunks then I cant get the table1.id again to fetch data from table2.Suppose table1 has unique row. Based on Table1.Id I can get more then one row from table2.Is it possible to achieve in ItemStreamReader or do I need to go for tasklet and pass my reader because now my writer has to write 10 k records which I will get from table1.
@Component
public class Reader1 extends JdbcCursorItemReader<Entity1> {
    private static final String query = "SELECT t2.*, t1.id FROM table2 t2, table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = t2.inputId";

    public Reader1(DataSource dataSource) {
        setName(getClass().getSimpleName());
        setDataSource(dataSource);
        setSql(query);
        setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Entity1.class));
    }

}

@Bean(name="Step1")
    public Step Step1(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws IOException {
        return new StepBuilder("Step1", jobRepository).<Entity1, Entity1>chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
                .reader(readItems())
                .writer(writeItems())
                .listener(writeListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Entity1> readItems() {
        Reader1 reader1 = new Reader1(datasource);
        return reader1;
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonFileItemWriter<Entity1> writeItems() throws IOException {
     
        return new JsonFileItemWriterBuilder<Entity1>()
                .jsonObjectMarshaller(new JacksonJsonObjectMarshaller<>())
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(filePath))
                .name("jsonFileItemWriter")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WriteListener writeListener() {
        JdbcTemplate  jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
        WriteListener writeListener = new WriteListener(jdbcTemplate);

        return writeListener;
    }

